# Unexpected stack trace form Spring-Security-SAML when generating SP metadata?

Tags: spring, shibboleth, spring-saml

I am attempting to integrate spring-security-saml with an existing application to allow that application to act as a service provider.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the metadata filter to work. The webapp boots up without any fuss, but when I hit $contextPath/saml/metadata, I receive the following stack trace in my logs.

```
2014-10-24 13:52:38,779 54025 [1045652139@qtp-718389251-8] WARN  org.mortbay.log - /sf/saml/metadata/
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No hosted service provider is configured and no alias was selected
        at org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl.populateLocalEntity(SAMLContextProviderImpl.java:311) ~[spring-security-saml2-core
-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl.populateLocalContext(SAMLContextProviderImpl.java:216) ~[spring-security-saml2-cor
e-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl.getLocalEntity(SAMLContextProviderImpl.java:107) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.
0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter.processMetadataDisplay(MetadataDisplayFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter.doFilter(MetadataDisplayFilter.java:88) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
```

My metadata configuration is included below:

```
  <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="metadataGenerator"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="metadataGenerator" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
    <!--<property name="entityBaseURL" value="${env.shibboleth.entityBaseUrl"/>-->
    <property name="bindingsSSO">
        <list>
            <value>redirect</value>
            <value>artifact</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="entityId" value="${env.shibboleth.entityId}"/>
    <prop
  </bean>
```

We are currently using:

- spring version: 4.0.4.RELEASE
- spring security version: 3.2.3.RELEASE
- spring-security-saml2 version: 1.0.0.RELEASE

At this point, I'm largely at a loss, as we're not trying to do a multi-tennancy setup, which is the only place which *alias* is mentioned at length, and from what I can see, the metadataGenerator defines a service provider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `metadataGeneratorFilter` needs to be executed before invocation of the `MetadataDisplayFilter`, make sure to include the following declaration in your `<security:http>` element:

```
<security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
```

Also, your value for `entityId` seems to suggest that you are using same `entityId` for both your IDP (Shibboleth) and SP (Spring SAML application). Make sure that the value is **unique** for both of the entities.

Comment: Hello Vladimir, do you happen to understand why the equivalent JavaConfig to your xml above  would not generate the metadata?
`http.addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class).addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);`

Many thanks, best regards

Comment: SAMLContextProviderImpl:244 will receive a null entityId as described in this question.